# Spring boot enable Global CORS support issue: only GET is working, POST, PUT and Delete are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cors

Update:
Now looking back more than a year later, I am giving an update hope that will help someone else.

Spring IO recommend using CSRF protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.
Since my app is an API and will be processed by a browser, so disable CSRF is not an approach.

CSRF is enabled with Spring Boot by default, you would need to add the following code to add a CSRF repository and a filter to add the CSRF token to your http requests. (The solution comes from here [Invalid CSRF Token in POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878189/invalid-csrf-token-in-post-request?answertab=votes#tab-top) )

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/templates/**", "/custom-fonts/**", "/api/profile/**", "/h2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class); // Register csrf filter.
               }
```

The filter & CsrfToken Repository part:

```
private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {

                    // Token is being added to the XSRF-TOKEN cookie.
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}   


private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }
```

---

Original Question I asked back in Feb 2016

I working on enabeing the Global CORS support for a Spring-boot RESTful API with Spring 4.

I am following the official Spring Boot Doc(https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) and have added this to my Application:

```
public class SomeApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SomeApiApplication.class, args);
    }


    //Enable Global CORS support for the application
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                        .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2") //What is this for?
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I don't get why only GET is working, for the rest of http calls, I am getting an error message saying "Invalid CORS request".  Do I miss anything in the set up? If  my set up is not right, GET should not work as well. I am very confussed.

Comment: Try to post XML configuration

Comment: I am using POSTMAN to test. For my request headers, I have Authorization and Content-Type.  I wonder if I need put some additional header there for CORS?

Comment: @Abdelhak: I am using Spring 4, should not have any XML in my code.

Comment: I had to manually specify all methods were allowed (including delete and patch which were previously failing CORS negotiation) - leaving out the .allowedMethods call does not automatically add all methods!

Answer (score 25):

I had a a similar issue, only HEAD GET and POST were working for me.
I found out that [`addCorsMappings`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/package-summary.html) has a default value for [`allowedMethods`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistration.html#allowedMethods-java.lang.String...-).

This code works for me:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: PUT method does not support for me. I added allowedMethods("*"); then it worked.

Comment: Indeed, only PUT, HEAD and POST are allowed by default; allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE") worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem - GET worked. POST didn't. I looked for an answer in the CORS domain but eventually, found that it was due to CSRF protection. 
To solve it, I disabled CSRF protection in the security configuration:

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SpringWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                **.csrf().disable()** //TODO: for production, must be reconfigured in order to disable only in specific cases. This line was added because without it, HTTP POST requests did not work. 
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
        }
```

Make sure you understand what you're doing: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/web-app-security.html#csrf

Answer (score 5):

Try to change `allowedOrigins` method to `.allowedOrigins("*")`. Postman is an extension and it runs in another "host".

But make sure that you understand the impacts: https://spring.io/understanding/CORS

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and after doing research what i found is, the browser looks for an HTTP header named **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in the response.

The browser sends an **OPTION request** to find out what methods like **PUTs, DELETE** are allowed. If the requested method is allowed from server side, then the browser will make the actual request, again passing or blocking the response depending on the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header in the response.
Simply add a spring bean, that will solve your problem.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
@Configuration
public class RestConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and figured out that @CrossOrigin on my controller had to be removed to solve the problem. Yet to figure out why that is causing "Invalid CORS request".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `SecurityConfig.java`. I had to mix various answers in this post to get it to work for me.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        // unblock post, put and delete requests
        http.csrf().disable();
        // enable cors
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

If you would like to allow all origins, replace `http://localhost:3000` with `*`

Answer (score 0):

Triple check that your path names align between your backend / front end application, as well as any path variables etc. If the contract is incorrect, OPTIONS will return a 403 because it can't find the correct API to use. It looks like a CORS issue in the browser, but root cause is a difference in contract.